# SQL Server 2008 Function that returns a Parameter

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have problems creating a function that returns a `date` parameter. I want to return `GETDATE()`, and launch the function with a trigger into a table. In other words, I want to use this function in an insert or update trigger to put the server date in my `fechconsol` column.

I tried this

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_InsertDateStamp(@FN_dateStamp date)
RETURN date
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @Return date
   SET @return = select GETDATE()
   RETURN @return
END
```

but I don't have any idea how to create a trigger with this.

Comment: If you just need `GETDATE()` result in trigger, don't use function, insert `GETDATE()` in trigger body.

Comment: It's one thing to have trouble with English, and another entirely to give no thought at all to capitalization, punctuation, or sentence structure. The original here was nearly unreadable.

Comment: i'am new in sql and i dont know much to respect, but i'am not sure if use a function or a trigger how explain in the first comment, in the case of use one trigger i am looking for the way to do this. (sorry for my bad english xD, i'm working to fix this problem).

Comment: Do you maybe simply want to have the current `GETDATE()` value along with other column-values in a newly inserted row in your table? What is your use case?

Comment: in my table with 5 columns, i need insert GETDATE() in one column called "fechconsol", and, int the more columns, i send the values with my java application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh maybe I know that you're trying to do.
If you just want to

> use this function in an insert or update trigger to put the server date in my fechconsol column.

then it's simplier can be done with DEFAULT CONSTRAINT:

```
ALTER TABLE [usu_sucursal] ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_usu_sucursal__fechconsol] DEFAULT (GETDATE()) FOR [fechconsol]
```

Comment: i have a table with the next colums: id_group, id_enterprise, id_branch, fechconsol, with my desktop app in java i send the first tree values, but i need that fechconsol are inserted with the trigger i write the next trigger:  

CREATE TRIGGER trInsertDate on usu_sucursal
INSTEAD OF INSERT
 AS
 INSERT INTO usu_sucursal(fechconsol) VALUES(GETDATE())}

but in the moment to save the information sql return a exception: that id_group not allow null params, i think that is for the trigger.

Comment: an apology for the structure, I'm learning to use the page and its text fields

Comment: @Telluz21, sorry for column name, I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Telluz21, in your case you surely don't need a trigger.